# Magento 2 UiRegistry can't get component element

Tags: php, magento2.2, knockoutjs

this my `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Asiantech_Postcode::css/jquery.Thailand.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="autocomplete" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/autocomplate</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`autocomplete.js`

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
'uiRegistry',
], function (
$,
Component,
checkoutData,
uiRegistry,
) {
"use strict";   
console.log(uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.postcode'));

return Component.extend({
    /**
     * Initialization method
     */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
    }
  });
});
```

but my result is `undefined',what's wrong with this component ?

Comment: You misspelled autocomplete.

Comment: I corrected the spelling but not the main issue, because this file must be run after `$(window).load(fn)`

Comment: okay. have you got you solution. If yes then I would love to see it.

Comment: Then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Anime 
i get new file `loader.js` this code :

```
define(['jquery'],function ($) {    
    var loaded_def = $.Deferred();
    $(window).ready(function () {
        loaded_def.resolve();        
    });
    return loaded_def.promise();
});
```

and define in `autocomplete.js`
this code

```
define([
...
'vendor_module/js/loader'
], function (
$,
...
Loader
) {
"use strict";
Loader.done(function(){
console.log(uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.postcode').uid);
});
return Component.extend({
/**
 * Initialization method
 */
initialize: function () {
    this._super();
}
});
});
```

it run !!!